# Router getCurrentNavigation(): is it safe to mutate the value it returned?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

```
      const currentNavigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
      const currentUrlTree = currentNavigation ? currentNavigation.extractedUrl : null;
      let route = [];
      if (currentUrlTree) {
        currentUrlTree.queryParams = {};
        route = [currentUrlTree.toString()];
      }

      this.router.navigate(route, {
        relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
        queryParams,
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
      });
```

I had implemented a function with the following content, which simply adds queryParams to the current route.

I am a little concerned about mutating the `queryParams` property of the `extractedUrl`. Is it safe to do this?

PS: This implementation is a part of a Service.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily! It should have been safe to mutate the `extractedUrl` property. According to https://angular.io/api/router/Navigation#description,
it says,

> extractedUrl : The initial target URL after being parsed with UrlSerializer.extract().

See the phrase *"after being parsed"*, it should have been parsed from the url.
Its actual implementation is here in this link: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/12.1.3/packages/router/src/router.ts#L610-L613

[image]

We can see that it is using the `extract()` function as described. BUT, if you are using the default urlHandlingStrategy, it is simply giving you what it got without any modification/parsing.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/b0854e2ec6a337cc639d405524aba225c9b45344/packages/router/src/url_handling_strategy.ts#L44

[image]

So, mutating that property can have unintended side-effects. If you really want to be on the safe side, you can use `UrlSerializer.parse()` to parse the full url and then carry-on emptying the `queryParams`.

```
      const currentNavigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
      const currentUrl = currentNavigation ? currentNavigation.extractedUrl.toString() : null;
      let route = [];
      if (currentUrl) {
        const parsedUrlTree = new DefaultUrlSerializer().parse(currentUrl);
        parsedUrlTree.queryParams = {};
        route = [parsedUrlTree.toString()];
      }

      this.router.navigate(route, {
        relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
        queryParams,
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge'
      });
```